# How can i change record delimiter in data collection rule in Add data source by Azure?

Tags: azure

Currently I see only "End-pf-line" as possible option on Record delimiter field.

How can I process a log file that contains multi-line log data?
Example:

> ERROR 2022-12-07 13:27:47,460 [AsyncHttpClient-7-2] [processor: ;
> event: ]
> org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.application.DefaultMuleApplication:
> There was '1' error while parsing the given file
> 'currenta-crm-api.xml'. Full list: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
> lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 13; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid
> content was found starting with element 'db:sql'. One of
> '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations,
> "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db":template-query-ref,
> "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db":in-param,
> "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db":parameterized-query .......

I could not figure how to change this option